# Creating Gui for python client server

Tags: python, user-interface, client-server

Help needed with my python project.
Unable to get the code for the client or server implemented with the Gui i created.
it is one based on book seller where the client is the buyer and the server is the seller.
Code written so far could be supplied upon request. 
please and thanks :)

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Yea this is not really a question. Please meet at least these criterias: Supply your code (we can not perform magic and see into the depths of your harddrive), state the preferred outcome, state the problem you're experiencing, if it's an error you should also consider pasting that somewhere here. If you want **us to create the gui for you** then you're in the wrong spot. There's a lot of examples out there but we ain't gona waste our time writing stuff from scratch for you (because then you won't learn shit and you'll come back with more of these "questions") :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop a GUI then please visit this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115495/is-python-any-good-for-gui-development). Here you can read different opinions regarding how to develop a GUI with python.

I personally would suggest you [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/).

Also, upon googling for a second I found this [link](http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonAndTwisted) , which maybe be helpful.